# How to determine which record wasn't found in an IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE MY_FIELD IN ('AAA','BBB','CCC', 'DDD');
```

and my table was:

```
ID FIELD1
1  AAA
2  CCC
3  DDD
4  FFF
```

The above sql statement would give me the 3 records in the database.

My question is how can I alter my SQL statement to find which record it didn't find? (i.e. Show me that BBB didnt match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`, `NOT IN`, or `NOT EXISTS` for that:

```
SELECT v.* 
FROM (SELECT 'AAA' as f FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'BBB' as f FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CCC' as f FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'DDD' as f FROM DUAL
     ) v LEFT JOIN
     MY_TABLE t
     ON v.f = t.my_field
WHERE t.my_field IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE MY_FIELD NOT IN ('AAA','BBB','CCC', 'DDD');
```